# how to retrieve all the input value in a div class

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to retrieve all the input value in this tr class

```
            <tr class="tr-shadow" id="myform">

                     <td>

                        <span class="status--process">
                        <input class="au-input au-input--sm" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for datas &amp; reports..." style="width: 90px;" />
                        </span>

                                </td>
                                 <td class="desc"><input class="au-input au-input--sm qty" type="text" name="search" placeholder="i.e. 20 EA" style="width: 100px;" />
                                            </td>
                                             <td class="status--process" >
                                                 <input class="au-input au-input--sm" type="text" name="search" placeholder="shipping cost" style="width: 120px; height: 30px;"  /><br>
                                            <select name="selectSm" id="SelectLm" class="form-control-sm form-control" style="width: 120px;">

                                                   <option value="0">Please select</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Option #1</option>
                                                    <option value="2">Option #2</option>
                                                    <option value="3">Option #3</option>
                                                    <option value="4">Option #4</option>
                                                    <option value="5">Option #5</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="postitem()">Submit</button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
```

I tried using this function

```
function postitem(index) {
   var formid='#myform'
    var panel= $(formid);
    var inputs = panel.find("input");
    console.log(inputs.value)

   }
```

but the text value are not being retrieved. What am I doing wrongly and how can I retrieve the text value for all the input?

Comment: Are the inputs prepopulated with data? Typically you would use an event such as `click` or `submit` after they have been typed into to do something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to get all values.

```
$('input').each(function(index){ console.log($(this).val()); });
```

Comment: how do you get the actual text input

Comment: What do you mean by the 'actual text input'? Are you referring to the select drop down? Your post does specifically mention getting the inputs, which is exactly what this does.

Comment: i edited my answer that's why his comment doesnt make sense now

Comment: For this method, remember to include this: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: this is dunamically created html how can narrow the above to input in a specific div id not all the input. for example inputs in id="myform"

Comment: find a way of using the selector $('input') and use it however you want depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use id's for the input fields and then get the value of the element at that id. You can do this like so, using the first input field as an example:

```js
function postitem(){
 console.log(document.getElementById('first_input').value);
}
```

```html
 <tr class="tr-shadow" id="myform">

                     <td>

                        <span class="status--process">
                        <input class="au-input au-input--sm" id = 'first_input' type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for datas &amp; reports..." style="width: 90px;" />
                        </span>

                                </td>
                                 <td class="desc"><input class="au-input au-input--sm qty" type="text" name="search" placeholder="i.e. 20 EA" style="width: 100px;" />
                                            </td>
                                             <td class="status--process" >
                                                 <input class="au-input au-input--sm" type="text" name="search" placeholder="shipping cost" style="width: 120px; height: 30px;"  /><br>
                                            <select name="selectSm" id="SelectLm" class="form-control-sm form-control" style="width: 120px;">

                                                   <option value="0">Please select</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Option #1</option>
                                                    <option value="2">Option #2</option>
                                                    <option value="3">Option #3</option>
                                                    <option value="4">Option #4</option>
                                                    <option value="5">Option #5</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="postitem()">Submit</button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put a class on each input control you want to capture, then use that class to select only the inputs that you want. For example I used .captureInput, and placed that class on each input and your select element.

```
function postitem() {               
  $('#myform').find('.captureInput').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
}
```

This will get you all of the values.

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript, using `document.getElementsByTagName`:

```
function findAll(){
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
   console.log(inputs[i].value);
  }
}
```